# SHELL send SIGHUP and get output from xterm

Tags: shell, timeout, xterm

Would like to know if there's a way to send SIGHUP to stop airodump after "n" seconds which is running in xterm and catch its output (ESSID, NAME) ?

```
Interface=$(airmon-ng | awk '!/Interface/ {print $2}')
xterm -hold -e airodump-ng $Interface &
```

I tried to run xterm with timeout but it didn't work out and I have no clue how to get the output of xterm.

Comment: You can capture output from programs inside `xterm` by dup'ing (`>&`) them to file descriptors beyond 2 and then dup'ing them back, but I have no idea how that interacts with `&`. Maybe use `<()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized, that "-hold" was the cause that made "timeout" not working properly. Also with adding "-w", airodump-ng creates a ".cap file" ($myfile) with my output in it.

```
xterm -e timeout --signal=SIGINT 5 airodump-ng $Interface -w $myfile
```